# Come tradurreste in italiano la parola "maintainer"?

Tags: translation

Ho visto la parola

> maintainer = responsabile della manutenzione di un programma

tradotta alcune volte con

> manutentore

altre volte con

> mantenitore

ma, sinceramente, nessuna delle due alternative mi entusiasma.

Come si potrebbe tradurre?

Comment: Entrambe sono attestate, per quel che vale ([manutentore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manutentore) e [manutentore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manutentore)): cioè, per lo meno non sono invenzioni fatte “a orecchio”. Poi, lo stabilirà l'uso quale delle due si affermerà. Tu comincia a usare quella che ti piace di più. ;-) Personalmente, forse userei “responsabile della manutenzione”.

Comment: Spero fortemente che l'orribile (in questo contesto) *mantenitore* non si affermi :) Anch'io sacrificherei la brevità per una espressione più "simpatica" (per me), come "addetto alla manutenzione".

Comment: Ovviamente qui sopra intendevo [manutentore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/manutentore) e [mantenitore](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mantenitore). Certo, il mantenitore fa pensare un po' a uno che ha una mantenuta...

Comment: @DaG Questo non l'avevo pensato ma non mi piaceva lo stesso :)

Comment: *Curatore* non è standard ma tutto sommato non starebbe male.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Senz'altro meglio di _mantenitore_ :)

Comment: @DaG mantenuta vuo dire concubina? In portoghese abbiamo 'teúda e manteúda' (tenuta e mantenuta) (a fermale you 'have' and pay the bills for). Il curioso è che trattasi di linguaggio legale anziano, sarebbe 'tida e mantida' in lingua normale, dunque sarà probabilmente d'origine italiana.

Comment: Esattamente, @entonio: è una donna con cui hai una relazione e a cui paghi tutte le spese. In italiano è il normale participio passato femminile di “mantenere”, ma è comunque una parola un po' antiquata. Un “mantenuto”, invece, è più un pappone, lo sfruttatore di una prostituta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il Ragazzini 2018 riporta:

> **maintainer** n. (*comput.*), manutentore, gestore di sistema informatico

Per il significato da te indicato, la traduzione suggerita sarebbe quindi *manutentore*.

Farei però attenzione nell'uso perché nell'industria meccanica tale termine indica comunemente chi si occupa della manutenzione delle macchine, e questo potrebbe generare qualche confusione.

Comment: Sto traducendo la documentazione di un'applicazione informatica che non riguarda l'industria meccanica, per cui il termine non può essere frainteso, grazie!

Comment: "Gestore di sistema informatico" mi sembra una pessima traduzione. Sembra adatta più a un sysadmin che non a un maintainer. "Sistema informatico" non è un termine che viene normalmente usato per riferirsi a un programma, ma piuttosto al computer su cui gira.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Sì, concordo. Ero stato tentato di proporre anch'io _curatore_, ma rischia di essere poco intuitivo.

Answer (score 1):

Dipende dai casi:
Manutentore: Il 'tecnico' che chiami quando il sistema ha problemi.
Mantenitore: il soggetto che ha in gestione il sistema e provvede al regolare funzionamento (eventualmente chiamando il manutentore se ci sono problemi)

Edit: -- non posso ancora commentare --
Fonti: i miei professori universitari (studio Ing. Informatica) usano i termini in questione con questi riferimenti

Comment: Benvenuto su IL.SE. Fonti?